# Regex replace till specific character in php

Tags: php, regex

Let's say I have a strings:

```
a) 'one4two2three1'
b) 'one4two2three1four#five7'
```

I want to replace all numbers from these strings with empty space ('') - untill '#' character

so final output should be:

```
a) 'onetwothree'
b) 'onetwothreefour#five7'
```

Is there a way to do it with preg_replace(), or any other regex function?

I'm trying to avoid an 'if' with strpos() and substr() and find more efficient way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PCRE verbs `(*SKIP)(*F)` to match and discard part after `#`:

```
$repl = preg_replace('/#[^#]*$(*SKIP)(*F)|\d+/m', '', $str);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/50XxeL/2)

`#[^#]*$(*SKIP)(*F)` will match and skip part after `#` in input and then we can replace all digits by empty string.

Comment: wow, that's what I was looking for! Are there any restrictions using this?

Comment: No restrictions since you're using PCRE (PHP) regex.

Comment: what does it mean 'using pcre regex'? I'm using simple PHP (5.3-till 7.0) - will it work? I hope I dont need any extensions/plugins/special circumstances...

Comment: No you don't need any extension. Regex engine used in PHP is `PCRE` compatible.

Comment: @user7201963 you can read more here, http://www.rexegg.com/backtracking-control-verbs.html